# 401 Unauthorized error or no message return in SignalR for WinForms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, signalr

I am trying to create simple SignalR hub between MVC server side and WinForms client side.

I have created NotificationHub class, specified as this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace PF.Timesheet.Service
{
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {

            return base.OnConnected();
        }
    }
}
```

While code on client side is this:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:30341/singalr");
var chat = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationHub");

string message2 = string.Empty;

chat.On<string, string>("broadcastMessage", (name, message) => { message2 = message; });

chat.On<string, string>("broadcastMessage", (name, message) =>
        this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
           RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText(String.Format("{0}: {1}" + Environment.NewLine, name, message)));

hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

I was trying to get message from broadcastMessage on any possible way, both by assigning it to some string variable 'message2' or by appending text to rich textbox control on UI.

If I make call like this:

```
hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

I will get 401 Unauthorized response from localhost where signalr is selfhosted. (local host is running in parallel as different solution within same project as client WinForms app).

What I am trying to do on server side is to push message to hub from code like this:

```
  var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
  context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage("NAM", "New entry created.");
```

If I remove Wait() from: `hubConnection.Start();` I won't get Unauthorized 401 error, but I wouldn't get message value as well.

Does anybody sees what I am doing wrongly here?

Things I've tried so far:

1. Trying to set up `EnableDetailedErrors` and `EnableJSONP` properties to true. I have read somewhere that SignalR hub has `[Authorized]` attribute by default and that this configuration should help.

```
    public class Startup
    {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
           WebApiConfig.Register(config);
           DependencyConfig.Initialize(config);
           Loging.Initialize();
           app.UseWebApi(config);
           app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
           {
               EnableDetailedErrors = true,
               EnableJSONP = true
           });
        }
     }
```

2. Trying to set `WindowsAuth` and `AnonymousAuth` properties for Server project to `Enabled`.

[image]

3. Checking if message was actually pushed to hub when using:

   context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage("NAM", "New entry created.");

Message was there.

Did anybody passed issue with being Unauthorized and was able to read messages from MVC Server SignalR hub to WinForms client?

Comment: Probably unrelated but there seems to be a typo in the hub uri

Comment: @LennartStoop Thanks for answering. On which typo do you mean? maybe I am missing something stupid like that.

Comment: I'm referring to the uri on the client side: shouldn't it be `signalr` instead of `singalr` ?

Comment: @LennartStoop Fixed that one, but problems still remains. :(

Comment: The reason you don't get an exception if you run without `.Wait()` is that `hubConnection.Start()` returns a `Task` that either needs to be `await`ed or be `.Wait()`ed or it will never run. So when you leave it out it doesn't try to connect (and you don't get the broadcasted message anyway).

Comment: When you use the default service endpoint (`/signalr`) I don't think you need to specify it, the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) doesn't. Not sure if that is the cause of your problem though.

Comment: @fredrik That is correct, I've just read status on Start() without Wait() and it is 'WaitingForActivation' so it never actually pass that start, it just continue without async call, so authorization never happened in that case. Not sure how to over come that Authorization issue.
I've also tried only using localhost uri without /signalr part, still same.

Comment: How are you hosting this? I'm thinking that maybe whichever server you're using is not set up for anonymous access.

Comment: @fredrik this is self-hosted SignalR within MVC Server project that is running on that 'http://localhost:30341'. And I didn't setup server so I am not 100% sure, it could be the case that server itself rejects anonymous access. I did try enabling AnonymousAuth on it but it didn't help.

Comment: Try disabling windows authentication. I don't know which order IIS Express evaluates authentication in cases like this

Comment: Do you have any authentication set up anywhere in this app? If so, update the question with that code as well.

Comment: @fredrik It was disabled by default before, I will return it back to Disable. I also try using DefaultNetworkCredentials from client:  hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; Didn't solved problem as well.

Comment: I was thinking more on serverside, if you want anonymous access the client shouldn't need to touch it at all. Looks like you will have to inspect everything in your app to see if something is adding authentication on the server side.

Comment: @fredrik I will do that, that is the only explanation left there, even though I don't see any additional authentication on server problem must be around that. Client sends other calls to server and getting data from it without any auth problems at all, the only issue occurs with signalR calls

Comment: @fredrik Found a problem, server had basic auth on, and it was expecting username/pass combination all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this on my own. Issue was that server (that was already setup before and not by me) had basic authentication with username and password.
This wasn't visible at all with any [Authorization] attribute or anything, but it was still there.

I solved it by setting up Credentials property on hubConfiguration:

```
hubConnection.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user.name", "password");
```

Authentication and connection to hub was successful and message was returned from server to client.